# Deny PHP execution in folder except one file in subfolder .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress installation with WordFence plugin running. That plugin creates an .htaccess file into uploads directory with a code execution protection. That code prevents execution of php files among others.

I would like to let that code continue running but with an exception. I would like to be able to execute one file into uploads subdirectory, and I would like to achieve that through .htaccess file, but I couldn't so far...

This is the directory structure:

```
 wp-content
 |__ uploads
      |__ .htaccess (here I am trying to do the magic!)
      |__ plugin-folder-name
           |__ download.php
```

I would like to deny all execution of php code inside uploads folder, except that one you can see above (download.php). Is that possible?

That's the code WordFence add to my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN Wordfence code execution protection
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_flag engine 0
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_php7.c>
        php_flag engine 0
    </IfModule>

    AddHandler cgi-script .php .phtml .php3 .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
    Options -ExecCGI
# END Wordfence code execution protection
```

And that's the code I'm writing to let that only file to be executed:

```
#
# First attempt -- IT DOES NOT WORK WORK!
#
<FilesMatch "download.php$">
    Order Deny,Allow 
    Allow from All 
</FilesMatch>

#
# Second attempt -- IT DOES NOT WORK EITHER!
#
<Files "plugin-folder-name/*">
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Can anyone help me, please?? THANKS!!

Comment: First of all - _why_ ...? What business does _executable code_ have being inside the _uploads_ folder in the first place?

Comment: Probably you need to undo the effect of `Options -ExecCGI`?

Comment: @04FS, I explain you _why_... That's the official plugin from a well known package delivery company in my country. I've installed it to manage shipments and print labels and invoices, and it has the `download.php` file installed into a subfolder of `uploads`. How can I undo the effect of `Options -ExecCGI` in that single file?

Comment: Try if `Options +ExecCGI` works inside the `Files` container.

Comment: @04FS, that didn't work for me. Thank you anyway!